# error pybind11 simple example: hpp header involved

Tags: c++, header, pybind11

I'm trying to run a simple example of pybind11.

Here is my compilation code(from the official website of pybind11):

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` wrapper.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

I get three files.

**funcs.cpp**

```
#include "funcs.hpp"

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
};
```

**funcs.hpp**

```
int add(int i, int j);
```

**wrapper.cpp**

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "funcs.hpp"

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m){
    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

and also a .py file to run the test

**main.py**

```
import example

if __name__  =='__main__':
    print(example.add(1, 2))
```

However, this throws me an error

```
$python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import example
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nirvana_kwai/dev/dev_setup/dark_magic/pybindtest/example.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Z3addii
  Referenced from: /Users/nirvana_kwai/dev/dev_setup/dark_magic/pybindtest/example.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/nirvana_kwai/dev/dev_setup/dark_magic/pybindtest/example.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

And if I only change one line in **wrapper.cpp** from `#include "funcs.hpp"` to `#include "funcs.cpp"`. The bug is fixed. I really don't understand where the problem is. I google a lot and fix it when I try to simplify the case and merge all code into one file.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I am new to stackoverflow, my reputation does not allow me to add a comment, so writing a suggestion as an answer. If @Lihaonan it solves your problem then thats great and if not just left a comment saying so. Thanks.

I have two suggestions for you to try:

**a)** Put the declaration under extern "C" and recompile and run your 
program. So you code in **func.hpp** will look like:

```
extern "C"
{
    int add(int i, int j);
}
```

I am suggesting this change assuming that due to **name mangling** you are facing this issue.

**b)** I am not sure why you did not included the func.cpp in compilation steps but the undefined reference comes when the run time environment is not able to find the definition of one of the declarations. So you compilation steps should be like:

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` wrapper.cpp func.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

Comment: Your second suggestion fix the problem, I need to include all cpp files for compilation. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

For someone who's looking to use setuptools instead of manually compiling, insert this into `setup.py` for your pybind11 project:

```py
ext_modules = [
    Pybind11Extension(
        <module_name>,
        sorted(glob("src/*.cpp")),
        define_macros=[('VERSION_INFO', __version__)],
    ),
]
```

`sorted(glob("src/*.cpp"))` then links to all `.cpp` files in `src/`. You can of course modify the call in `glob()` however you like.